# Using Sequelize Subquery

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am completely new to both nodejs and SQL / Sequelize.
But I fight my way through!

I have a query here, which I would like to implement with Sequelize.
If I am already informed, I can do this with `sequelize.literal`.

Maybe you can help me.

```
SELECT ytd.*
FROM youtubedata ytd
WHERE ytd.date = (SELECT MAX(ytd2.date) FROM youtubedata ytd2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const items = await database.youtubedata.findAll({
where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('date'), '=', Sequelize.literal('(SELECT MAX(ytd2.date) FROM youtubedata ytd2)'))
})
```

Comment: With a few minor changes, it worked wonderfully. Thank you!